# Can anyone Tell about any tools on toplayer of iptables to block port?

Tags: iptables, firewall

I am looking to block my all ports except few ports. I know how to do it via iptables. But I am looking for some tools on the top of iptables. so that if I uninstall that everything will back to normal.

Comment: See "Easy configuration via GUI" at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo

Comment: "so that if I uninstall that everything will back to normal" not going to be the case. iptables are gone on every boot and you need to edit a startup script to reload them on every boot. *Uninstalling is removing that alteration*.